# CouchDB 1.6: Configuring replications for databases on foreign nodes

Tags: couchdb, replication

I use CouchDB 1.6.1 on two separate servers (server A and server B).

For consistency sake I have been configuring all replications on server A. We have many databases. Each database has a 'push to B' and a 'pull from B' rep.

However, I now want to subdivide a database on server B. i.e.

dbOnA => dbOnB

dbOnB => subDbOnB1 (with repFilterB1)

dbOnB => subDbOnB2 (with repFilgerB2)

dbOnB => subDbOnB3 (with repFilgerB3)

etc.

Is there anything wrong with configuring these reps on server A?

Compared to configuring these same reps on server B, where the 'local' database is, am I making any tradeoffs wrt performance? efficiency? etc.

==== EDIT ====

To add background:

- server 1 has CouchDB installed
- server 2 has Barrel installed
- I would like to keep configuration documents installed in Couch only
- There are tools that interact with server 1, but not server 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why you want to configure everything on server A. Sure, the replication you create would have full URL' s for all replications on server B. When I setup sth. like this, I create a _replication document on each server like this:

on server A: pull from B
on server B: pull from A

So the replication process is started on each server and is pulling. When subdividing server B, I see no reason to not setup the replication on server B. I don't see any performance tradeoffs when setting this up on server B - the opposite is the case if at all.

Comment: We have tools that interact with server a, not server b. Also. Server B is running barrel not couch

Comment: well, that would have been an interesting info ;-)

Comment: Addressed :). Thanks for the input

Comment: Incidentally. Why do you prefer to have pulling replications from the perspective of the local server instead of pushing?

Comment: iirc this is the proposed way (pull vs. push) but I am sorry to admit, that I can't find the discussion where that was addressed ... it may also be outdated already, at least in the process of optimising the replicator again in CouchDB 2.0 (https://blog.couchdb.org/2016/08/15/feature-replication/) although the protocol did not change. For me it's common habit how I do it ;-). If looking at the processes that have to be spawned I think it's natural to distribute them as much as possible to different machines

Comment: here is a fairly thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@couchdb.apache.org/msg12930.html - again old ;-)